# C#: Unable to create DirectX device. Neither Hardware type or Software type works

Tags: c#, directx, device, managed-directx

I'm trying to create a DirectX device through the following code:

```
Caps deviceCapability;
int deviceAdapter = Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter;

try
{
    deviceCapability = Manager.GetDeviceCaps(
        deviceAdapter, DeviceType.Hardware);
}
catch (Exception ex1)
{
    try
    {
        deviceCapability = Manager.GetDeviceCaps(
            deviceAdapter, DeviceType.Software);
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        deviceCapability = Manager.GetDeviceCaps(
            deviceAdapter, DeviceType.Reference);
    }
}

CreateFlags deviceFlags = CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing;
if(deviceCapability.DeviceCaps.SupportsHardwareTransformAndLight == true)
{
    deviceFlags = CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing;
}

mDevice = new Device(deviceAdapter, deviceCapability.DeviceType,
    mInvisiblePanel, deviceFlags, mPresentParams);
```

The problem is that this only works on some computers (such as my work computer), while it doesn't on others (to be specific, a Panasonic CF-19 Toughbook).  I've checked to make sure the offending PC has hardware acceleration enabled via dxdiag, and it still doesn't budge.

Unfortunately, the only error message I get is, "Error on the Application."  I've even stuck several message boxes between the above code, and it never seems to hit the ex1 and ex2 catch block.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: Sorry, I just realized I forgot to show my PresentParameters.

```
// Setup the device parameters
PresentParameters mPresentParams = new PresentParameters();
mPresentParams.Windowed = true;
mPresentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
mPresentParams.AutoDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.D16;
mPresentParams.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
///* TODO: Anti-aliasing is not working
mPresentParams.MultiSample = MultiSampleType.NonMaskable;
mPresentParams.MultiSampleQuality = 0;
```

Comment: Managed DirectX has been deprecated for 4 years now?  This stuff runs out of gas.  The August 2007 SDK version was the last one that still supported it, I imagine you need a matching version of DirectX on the machine.  Version 9, I think.  Use XNA to move forward.

Comment: Yes, I have the same DirectX on the Toughbook and my machine.  At least, according to dxdiag.

Comment: If XNA isn't your thing SlimDX is a wrapper of the DirectX9-11 C++ commands into C#. There're some basic tutorials, but past then you'll need to work on your own or ask questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.  Darn, I feel stupid already.

Reducing the PresentParameters to just these 3 lines made it work on the Toughbook.

```
// Setup the device parameters
PresentParameters mPresentParams = new PresentParameters();
mPresentParams.Windowed = true;
mPresentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
```